# c++ return template function

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have functions of this type:

```
type uniRndtype()
{
    return typeValue;
}
```

and now I'm trying to wrap them inside another template function like this:

```
template<typename T>
T(* uniRndType(void))()
{
    if (is_same<T, bool>::value)
    {
        return uniRndBool;
    } else if (is_same<T, char>::value)
    {
        return uniRndChar;
    } else
    ...
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
uniRndType<int>();
```

But I'm getting an error: **"error: return value type does not match the function type"** 
because each return has a different type..

I there a way to make it work? Because from a runtime point of view I see no errors, only the compiler have problems.

Comment: Use `static_cast` to cast the function to your return type.

Comment: You appear to be mixing compile-time and run-time logistics. T is predetermined by the invoker at compile-time; not run-time

Comment: The error is because all your return types have to be compatible with `T` in order to instanciate the method. If you  called it with a string, `uniRndType<std::string>()` then how would the compiler handle the fact you've got code that returns a boolean value?

Comment: Thanks, changing each return to `return (T(*)(void))uniRndType;` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that while the optimiser can eliminate dead code branches, the front-end (lexical, syntactic & semantic analysis) can't. Which means all code in a template instantiation must be valid. That is, even though in this:

```
if (is_same<T, bool>::value)
{
    return uniRndBool;
}
```

the body will never be executed when `T` is `char`, it must still be valid C++ code. And of course it's not, because `uniRndBool` doesn't have the correct type.

You have two options: a hackish one which works in your particular case, and a generic one.

The hackish one is using `reinterpret_cast<T(*)()>` in all the `return` statements. For the correct `T` brach, it will be a no-op. The other branches will never be executed at runtime, so all will be fine.

The other solution is to use template specialisation. Since it's a [bad idea to specialise function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), you could use the well-known "delegate to class" trick:

```
template <class T>
struct uniRndTypeHelper;

template <>
struct uniRndTypeHelper<bool>
{
  static bool (*get())() { return uniRndBool; }
};

template <>
struct uniRndTypeHelper<char>
{
  static char (*get())() { return uniRndChar; }
};

template<typename T>
T(* uniRndType(void))()
{
  return uniRndTypeHelper<T>::get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T> T (*uniRndType())()
{
    //else
    ...
}

template <> bool (*uniRndType())()
{
    return uniRndBool;
}

template <> char (*uniRndType())()
{
    return uniRndChar;
}
```

That's all.

edit: In principle, we must do like @Angew. but it's little troublesome

Comment: so the second and third functions are overloading, but what is the first? removing it causes errors, but at the same time its empty..

Comment: @Vladp these aren't function overloading, but function template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because when the compiler expands the template method for a given type the method has to be valid. Your type, T, needs to be compatible with all the return types listed, eg `bool`, `char`, etc. As I mentioned in the comments, if you passed in a `std::string` you wouldn't expect the method to work, would you?

One way around this is to use [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) to indicate what you want for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler needs to know what types will be used by functions/methods at compile time. At this point you must instantiate this template function with types which it may receive as template parameter, like @ikh wrote here.

But, if you are using template class with template methods, you have 2 ways:

1) Simply write realization of each template method in .h file (right in the place where you declaring template class body) instead of prototypes only;

2) Or after declaring prototypes in .h file you need to instatiate this template class with template parameters which it may receive.